# Markdown: how to make numbered list without writing the actual numbers

Tags: markdown, numbered-list

Is it possible to make markdown numbered lists without writing the actual numbers?

For example, sometimes I have long numbered lists (10+ entries long).  If I insert an item after the second list item, I have to update all item numbers afterwards.

---

**More Detail**

Well-known way to make numbered lists:

```
1. Foo
2. Bar
3. Baz
```

What I would like is something like the below, and have it rendered just like any other numbered list.

```
#. Foo
#. Bar
#. Baz
```

---

**Pre-addressing Obvious Workaround**

I know one *technically* doesn't have to update the numbers, and that it will be auto-rendered with a sequentially-increasing numbered list.

However, this results in the source code being "messy" (see below), and I would prefer not to have any numbers included and still get a numbered list.

```
1. Foo
9001. Spam
2. Bar
3. Baz
```

Comment: Even though the question isn't totally the same as mine (see the "Pre-addressing Obvious Workaround" above), it actually converges to the same answer as @TomWillis's below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you OK with using "1." for each item in your ordered list?

```
1. Foo
1. Spam
1. Bar
1. Baz
1. Qux
```

It's the same for every member of you ordered lists, so there is a certain neatness you may desire, and gives you the desired output, while living within the constraints of MarkDown.

https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#ordered-lists

Comment: yes that's right on track!  If no other better answers show up, I will mark yours as the accepted answer