# math equations in ordered lists in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

I am trying to format math equations in a Jupyter notebook. Specifically, I want to add math equations embedded in text in an ordered list, similar to how \begin{enumerate} works in Latex. From what I understand, I should format using html, but write the math in MathJax.

Here is an example of what I want it to look [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn7zk.png).

Here is an example of what I have tried.

```
<ol type="a">
<li> It should look something like this $b= \begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 2\\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$<\li>
<li> and be able to start an equation in between as well
$$
A= \begin{pmatrix}\epsilon & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
</ol>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown: how to make numbered list without writing the actual numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64918160/markdown-how-to-make-numbered-list-without-writing-the-actual-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use a markdown cell combining two things:

- numbered list-specifying Markdown elements (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77277329/math-equations-in-ordered-lists-in-jupyter-notebook/77281680#comment136239519_77277329), see the link in [Tom Willis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64918312/8508004) to the markdown specification guide)
- MathJax rendering using both in-line and paragraph typesetting style, see [here](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/mathematics.html?highlight=paragraph#tex-and-latex-input) and [here](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/faq.html?highlight=paragraph#some-of-my-mathematics-is-too-large-or-too-small-how-do-i-get-it-right).

No need for the HTML you've been including.
Your stated goal can be achieved with this text in markdown cell in a Jupyter `.ipynb` file:

```markdown
1. It should look something like this $b= \begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 2\\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$

1. and be able to start an equation in between as well:
$$
A= \begin{pmatrix}\epsilon & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

The result of that:
[image]

Fortunately, the use of centered equation doesn't interrupt the numbering and so you can continue even adding to the list. I find with some other formatting it kicks things out and doesn't continue the numbering. Yet, right now this works:

```markdown
1. It should look something like this $b= \begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 2\\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$

1. and be able to start an equation in between as well:
$$
A= \begin{pmatrix}\epsilon & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

1. It will even continue the numbering correctly after that $b= \begin{pmatrix} 201\\ 84\\ -19 \end{pmatrix}$
```

The result:
[image]

---

---

By the way, if you wanted to generate such markdown rendering programmatically from a code cell within a Jupyter `.ipynb` file that is possible, too, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-add-markdown-inside-a-function-to-pretty-print-equation/2719/2?u=fomightez) and refereinces therein, especially [this succinct StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035217/8508004).